# java thread interleaving

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to interleave the execution of two independent threads. such that both have a run method with 10 iterations and after every iteration i want to context switch the threads.

thread A starts and after doing something like printing passes control to thread B. then thread B prints and passes control back to A and so on until both finish.

What is the effective mechanism to do this?

I'm attaching a sample code. hope you can help.

```
// Suspending and resuming a thread for Java 2

class NewThread implements Runnable {
  String name; // name of thread
  Thread t;
 // boolean suspendFlag;

  NewThread(String threadname) {
    name = threadname;
    t = new Thread(this, name);
    System.out.println("New thread: " + t);
  //  suspendFlag = false;
    t.start(); // Start the thread
  }
  public String getState()
  {
    Thread t=Thread.currentThread();

    return t.getState().toString(); 
  }
  // This is the entry point for thread.
  public void run() {
    try {
      for(int i = 15; i > 0; i--) {
        System.out.println(name + ": " + i);
        Thread.sleep(200);
        synchronized(this) {
            //SuspendResume.suspendFlag2=false;
            SuspendResume.suspendFlag1=true;
          while(SuspendResume.suspendFlag1) {
            wait();
            //System.out.println(SuspendResume.ob1.t.getState().toString());
           // if(SuspendResume.ob2.t.getState().toString()=="WAITING")
            //  SuspendResume.ob2.t.notify();
          }
        }
      }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      System.out.println(name + " interrupted.");
    }
    System.out.println(name + " exiting.");
  }

  void mysuspend() {
 //   suspendFlag = true;
  }

  synchronized void myresume() {
   // suspendFlag = false;
    notify();
  }
}
class NewThread2 implements Runnable {
      String name; // name of thread
      Thread t;
     // boolean suspendFlag;

      NewThread2(String threadname) {
        name = threadname;
        t = new Thread(this, name);
        System.out.println("New thread: " + t);
      //  suspendFlag = false;
        t.start(); // Start the thread
      }
      public String getState()
      {
        Thread t=Thread.currentThread();

        return t.getState().toString(); 
      }
      // This is the entry point for thread.
      public void run() {
        try {
          for(int i = 15; i > 0; i--) {
            System.out.println(name + ": " + i);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            synchronized(this) {
                //SuspendResume.suspendFlag1=false;
                //while(SuspendResume.suspendFlag1) {
         //     while(suspendFlag) {
                //wait();
                //System.out.println(SuspendResume.ob2.t.getState().toString());
                //if(SuspendResume.ob1.t.getState().toString()=="WAITING")
                //SuspendResume.ob1.t.notify();
              //}
                SuspendResume.suspendFlag1=false;
                notify();
            }
          }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          System.out.println(name + " interrupted.");
        }
        System.out.println(name + " exiting.");
      }

      void mysuspend() {
     //   suspendFlag = true;
      }

      synchronized void myresume() {
       // suspendFlag = false;
        notify();
      }
    }
class SuspendResume {
     static boolean suspendFlag1=false;
    static NewThread ob1 = new NewThread("One");
    static NewThread2 ob2 = new NewThread2("Two");

   // static boolean suspendFlag2=false;

  public static void main(String args[]) {


    try {
      //Thread.sleep(1000);
      //ob1.mysuspend();
      //System.out.println("Suspending thread One");
      //Thread.sleep(1000);
      //ob1.myresume();
      //System.out.println("Resuming thread One");
     // ob2.mysuspend();
      //System.out.println("Suspending thread Two");
      Thread.sleep(1000);
     // ob2.myresume();
      //System.out.println("Resuming thread Two");
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      System.out.println("Main thread Interrupted");
    }

    // wait for threads to finish
    try {
      System.out.println("Waiting for threads to finish.");
      System.out.println(ob1.getState());
      System.out.println(ob1.getState());
      ob1.t.join();
      ob2.t.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      System.out.println("Main thread Interrupted");
    }

    System.out.println("Main thread exiting.");
  }
}
```

Comment: First, you may have clean your code before posting it.You may use `Thread.yield()` method. It relinquishes the CPU. But it does not suspend the calling thread, it is in the ready queue.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  For the most part, threads complete a unit of work and then exit.  A controlling thread can start threads and wait until they are complete.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc for the most part, threads are written as while loops and never terminate until app close time.

Comment: I've made something's wrong, so to be complete... If you really want to obtain a kind of serialization of the concurrent executions (it is called co-routines) then you must use a some kind of `wait()/notify()` mechanism. But are you really sure that you need such behaviour ? If yes, then `synchronize()` on a common object, use `wait()/notify()` and use a variable to control who's authorized to continue.

Comment: If any of the answers below has been helpful you should upvote them and possibly select one as the accepted answer.

Comment: what i actually want to do is that given some threads and given a sequence of execution e.g A,B,C,A,B,C or maybe C,B,B,A,C,A i would like my threads execute according to the sequence provided. Whenever a thread yields, it should switch context to the next thread in sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I'm not sure what kind of scenario you have where you want to run two threads sequentially over and over again.  That sounds like a single thread running two different methods in a loop.  None-the-less, it sounds like an interesting challenge so I took it up.

Making use of Java 5's [Exchanger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Exchanger.html) class, the solution gets pretty small.  I ended up with a single [Runnable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) class.  I use two instances of them to pass around a boolean true and boolean false to each other.  The Exchanger class facilitates the passing around of the boolean values in a thread safe manner.  A Runnable only 'executes' its code when it has the boolean true value.

```
package interleavedexample;

import java.util.concurrent.Exchanger;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 */
public class InterleavedRunnable implements Runnable {

  private final String name;

  private final Exchanger<Boolean> exchanger;

  private Boolean state;

  public InterleavedRunnable(String name, Exchanger<Boolean> exchanger, 
       Boolean state) {
    this.name = name;
    this.exchanger = exchanger;
    this.state = state;
  }         

  @Override
  public void run() {
    try {
      while (true) {
        if (state) {
          Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).info(name + " is running");
        }
        state = exchanger.exchange(state);
      }
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(name).info("Interrupted");
    }
  }
```

Setting up the runnables are quite easy:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Exchanger<Boolean> exchanger = new Exchanger<Boolean>();
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(new InterleavedRunnable("Thread 1", exchanger, true));
    Thread thread2 = new Thread(new InterleavedRunnable("Thread 2", exchanger, false));
    thread1.start();
    thread2.start();
  }
```

Anytime you can find existing functionality within the Java API (or well known libraries), you should utilize them to the fullest extent.  The less lines of code you write the less lines there are to maintain.

Comment: this is very neat and do you think that it would work for the case I have mentioned."what i actually want to do is that given some threads and given a sequence of execution e.g A,B,C,A,B,C or maybe C,B,B,A,C,A i would like my threads execute according to the sequence provided. Whenever a thread yields, it should switch context to the next thread in sequence."

Answer (score 1):

The 'OS Sycnro 101' solution is to use two semaphores, one for each thread, and swap over one 'GO' token/unit between them.  Start both threads and then give the token to whichever thread you want to go first.

Answer (score 1):

Use wait and notify for this.

```
public class Thread1 implements Runnable {

@Override
public void run() {
    while(true){
        synchronized (Main.obj) {
            try {
                Main.obj.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        System.out.println("1");



        synchronized (Main.obj) {

            Main.obj.notify();

        }
    }

}

}


public class Thread2 implements Runnable{

@Override
public void run() {
    while(true){
        synchronized (Main.obj) {
            try {
                Main.obj.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("2");
        synchronized (Main.obj) {

            Main.obj.notify();

        }
    }

}
}


public class Main {

public volatile static Object obj =  new Object();

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Thread1());
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Thread2());
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    synchronized (obj) {
        obj.notifyAll();
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did not get your question correctly. If you want to execute thread B only after thread A execution is over, then there is no point of multi-threading at all. You can simply put the thread B contents in thread A run() method.

Still if it is very much required then you can try using wait() and notify() methods on two objects . Something like this.

```
Class ClassA implements runnable{
    Message messageA;
    Message messageB;
    public ClassA(Message messageA,,Message messageB){
        this.messageA = messageA;
        this.messageB = messageB;
    }
    public void run(){
        for(;loop contition;){
            //code here
            messageB.notify();
            messageA.wait();
        }
    }
}
Class ClassB implements runnable{
    Message messageA;
    Message messageB;
    public ClassB(Message messageA,Message messageB){
        this.messageA = messageA;
        this.messageB = messageB;
    }
    public void run(){
        for(;loop condition;){
            messageB.wait();
            //code here
            messageA.notify();
        }
    }
}
```

- now create two objects in main messageA and messageB and pass both of them in the constructor of each thread.